# Why does context={'request': self.request} need in serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Today I dig into django-rest-auth package a bit. And I have no idea what `context={'request': self.request}` for in `get_response` and `post` function.

They say context parameter is for including extra context to serializer. But below the codes, it seems not necessary to put context parameter. Is there something I have missed?

context: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

django-rest-auth : https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/views.py

```
def get_response(self):
    serializer_class = self.get_response_serializer()

    if getattr(settings, 'REST_USE_JWT', False):
        data = {
            'user': self.user,
            'token': self.token
        }
        serializer = serializer_class(instance=data,
                                      context={'request': self.request})
    else:
        serializer = serializer_class(instance=self.token,
                                      context={'request': self.request})

    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = request
    self.serializer = self.get_serializer(data=self.request.data,
                                          context={'request': request})
    self.serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    self.login()
    return self.get_response()
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you need request's data inside serializer method. For this case you can provide request to serializer's context. For example if you look into [`PasswordResetSerializer`](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/serializers.py#L153) you'll see in `save` method `use_https` option which calculated based on the request passed with context argument:

```
def save(self):
    request = self.context.get('request')
    # Set some values to trigger the send_email method.
    opts = {
        'use_https': request.is_secure(),
        'from_email': getattr(settings, 'DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL'),
        'request': request,
    }
```

Also you can check if user is authenticated or not and depends on it return one data or another on serializer level.